# PyWebIO with HTTPS

Tags: python

I'm trying to deploy a very simple PyWebIO Application in my local network, but I'm also trying to make it available via HTTPS, so that the browser does not "complain" about it being insecure.

What is the easiest way to set up a PyWebIO Application with HTTPS?

I have been trying to pass tornados `ssl_options=SSLContext` like this:
`pywebio.start_server(hello_world, ssl_options=ctx, port=1337, debug=True)` but it didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: I actually found a solution using FastAPI:
```
pywebio.platform.fastapi.start_server(
        hello, debug=True, ssl_certfile=PATH_TO_THE_CERT, port=1337, host="YOUR_HOSTNAME"
    )```

https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platform.html#fastapi-starlette-support

Comment: If you found a solution, please read [answer].